# The relationship between IP address and AS number

Tags: ip, network, bgp, internet, network-core

I've recently been looking for the IP prefixes originating from a specific AS. And there are a few questions I'd like to get confirmed.

1. We can register IP addresses and ASN from RIR. But where can we get the accurate mapping between ASN and the IP prefix? Is there an official information distribution agency?
2. As far as I know, one IP address is owned by one AS. However, I find 8.8.8 belongs to different ASes from bgp.he.net. I also don't know why different ASes have overlapping prefixes. (8.0.0.0/12 - 8.8.8.0/24) Is this a data platform problem or the result of route aggregation?

[image]

Comment: The AS concept is really decoupled from the IP addressing concept. You could certainly set up a transit AS between two other ASes and use only private addresses, or one or two public addresses without advertising any of your addressing because only the two ASes for which you are providing transit services need to know only your directly connected addresses and not advertise them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up two things here: ownership of the IP-range and the right to advertise IP addresses. Ownership of IP addresses has nothing to do with ASN's. The owner of an IP range may allow one or more ASNs to advertise their IP's. That can be done by registering route objects in one of the internet routing registries (IRRs). All regional internet registries (RIRs, like RIPE, ARIN, etc) operate one, but there are also others like RADB. Another way to let others know that a specific ASN is allowed to advertise an IP range is by creating RPKI route origin attestations (ROAs). Both route objects and ROAs link an IP range to an ASN.

Your example of the 8.0.0.0 space shows that Level3 is authorized to advertise the /9, but Google's AS15169 is alllowed to advertise the 8.8.8.0/24 from that /9. It has nothing to do with ownership of the IP range.

Comment: Got it! Then how can we get all IP prefixes owned by a specific AS through official public information on BGP?

Comment: Like I said: prefixes aren’t owned by an ASN, they’re owned by an organization and can be announced by one or more ASNs.

Comment: Perhaps I was not very clear. If an ISP registers some IP prefixes and an AS number to provide service, can we say these IP prefixes form the AS? I thought "the prefixes owned by an AS" refer to the network devices' ip addresses in that AS. @TeunVink

Comment: @wyb, "_can we say these IP prefixes form the AS?_" No. You are confusing two different concepts. AS (Autonomous System) only means that the entity with the AS is autonomously managed; it can do what it likes within its own network. An AS can, or not, advertise prefixes to other ASes, and that really has nothing to do with the IP prefixes that may be assigned to an entity that has an AS. The DoD has several very large prefixes assigned to it, but does not advertise some, so other ASes may use those internally, and the DoD has authorized outside ASes to advertise some of them.

Comment: In addition to what Ron said, an ASN can also announce prefixes belonging to another (downstream) ASN.

Comment: @RonMaupin so the public IP addresses used by network devices within an AS are authorized by the IP address owners, and it has nothing to do with the entity owning the AS. Sometimes they(IP and ASN) are owned by the same entity. Is that right? And how can we get the public IP addresses used by network devices within an AS?

Comment: @wyb, "_the public IP addresses used by network devices within an AS are authorized by the IP address owners, and it has nothing to do with the entity owning the AS._" No. You are again trying to tie completely different concepts. The addressing used inside an AS can be any addressing the AS owner wants to use. No outside entity can dictate how networking is done inside an AS, and that is the entire point of an AS (the ."A" is for Autonomous).

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks so much for your patience. Assume that there is a web server connected to a router of AS `E`. The IP address of the web server is `1.2.3.4` and we can visit it through the Internet. Isn't `1.2.3.4` authorized to use by its owner?

Comment: @wyb Yes, but that is not an _internal_ use of an address, which is what you asked about. Internally, the AS could have that server or anything else addressed differently. Also, understand that IANA owns all the IP addressing, and it authorizes the RIRs to assign addressing it has assigned to each RIR to other companies (not only ISPs).

Comment: @RonMaupin, I’m sorry to mix everything up. I don’t know how to describe the public ip addresses of the devices within an AS, which we can visit through the Internet. I incorrectly thought “these ip addresses are owned by the original AS”.

Comment: @TeunVink, I search a lot based on your answer, and there are some statements I’d like to know whether they’re right. `Level3 is allowed to advertise 8.0.0.0/9 and It is the origin AS of this prefix. Due to the subnet 8.8.8.0/24 advertised by another AS Google, we can infer that Level3 makes a route aggregation here. But Level3 can not be marked as the origin in Route Object, if 8.0.0.0/9 is not owned by just one organization`.

Comment: Route aggregation is irrelevant here, since you're looking at routing registries, not routing tables. The /9 is assigned to Level3. They allocated that /24 to Google to use for. 8.0.0.0/9 *IS* assigned to one organisation (Level3) and can be originated by only that organisation. Parts of that /9 were assigned to other networks.

Comment: @TeunVink, I do find that /9 in a BGP Routing Table project - `thyme.panic.net`. It’s path is [2516 3356(Level3)].

Comment: But it's not an aggregation, since the /24 is also in the routing table. It is a less specific route, but that's not the same as aggregation.

Comment: @TeunVink, could you please explain further? I think the AS originating that /24 may be multi-homed, making that /24 also in the routing table. (Sorry to have disturbed you for so long. But I could not find any BGP details on Google.)

Comment: No, the /24 is not multihomed. Prefixes can't be multihomed, ASNs can be. What you MAY mean, is that there are multiple origins for the /24, for which the correct term is 'anycasted'. That is not the case here, only one ASN (Google) is announcing the /24. Level3 is announcing the /9, but since more specific routes win from less specific routes, traffic will get routed to Google.

Comment: @TeunVink, thanks a lot for your help. I lack hands-on experience, which makes my ideas may be just possible in theory. In the case above, I thought Google has more than one upstream ASes. Level3 receives /24 from Google and its other downstream ASes. So Level3 makes the /9 super-prefix and advertises /9. At the same time, Google advertises its own 8.8.8.0/24 to other upstream ASes, making 8.8.8.0/24 also in the global routing table. `If this is impractical, please just let me know and I won't pursue it any further`.

Comment: What you're saying is correct. You may have meant this the whole time, but were using wrong terms like multihoming and aggregation to describe it.